# Prove Equality in Holder's Inequality Given these Restrictions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

Consider Holder's Inequality, which states that given a measurable set $E$, $1\leq p<\infty$, and $q$ the conjugate of $p$ (defined by $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$), if $f\in L^p(E)$ and $g\in L^q(E)$, then $f\cdot g\in L^1(E)$ and $||fg||_1\leq ||f||_p||g||_q$.

We want to see that $||fg||_1 = ||f||_p||g||_q$ if and only if there exist constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ not both zero such that $\alpha|f|^p=\beta|g|^q$ a.e. on $E$.

I really don't know where to start with this proof and would appreciate help!

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $\|f\|_p=\|g\|_q=1$. Then you have $\|fg\|_1=1$. That is, using [Young's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products),
$$
1=\int_E |fg|\leq \,\int_E\left(\frac{|f|^p}p+\frac{|g|^q}q\right)=\frac{\|f\|_p^p}p+\frac{\|g\|_q^q}q=1. 
$$
Thus 
$$
\int_E\left(\frac{|f|^p}p+\frac{|g|^q}q-|fg|\right)=0.
$$
But the integral is non-negative (due to Young's Inequality) and so 
$$
|fg|=\frac{|f|^p}p+\frac{|g|^q}q
$$
almost everywhere. Now you are reduced to the case of equality in Young's Inequality.

Comment: What if $p = 1$ so that $q =\infty$?

Comment: In that case the equality becomes $$\int_E |f|\,(\|g\|_\infty-|g|)=0,$$ so $|g|=\|g\|_\infty$ whenever $f\ne0$.

Comment: What is wrong with this counterexample?: Consider $p = 1$, $E = [0,1]$, and unnormalized constant functions $f = 1$, $g = 2$. Equality $||fg||_1 = ||f||_1||g||_\infty$ is true, but there are no constants $\alpha,\beta$ not both zero such that $\alpha|f| =\beta|g|^\infty$ on $E$, that is, $\alpha =\beta\infty$ on $E$.

Comment: I never said that those constants exist. I literally said "$|g|=\|g\|_\infty$ whenever $f\ne0$".

Comment: I agreed with your first comment (thus the upvote). My concern is that the claim in MathStudent1324's question is false for $p=1$. Do you concur? (Your answer uses Young's inequality which, according to the link, is for $p > 1$.)

Comment: Yes, of course.